# Mojibake (strange Chinese characters) in WinBUGS 1.43

Tags: encode, winbugs, mojibake

I installed the WinBUGS 1.43, and haven't do any other things. However, mojibake occurs. For example: in

> Help >> User manual

(see Figure below).
[image: Figure]

I thought it may due to the language used in Win10 system. However, the language in my system is already English (see [image: here]).

Why do these strange characters occur?

**Further information:**

I find in WinBUGS's text editor, mojibake also occurs if I type Chinese character ([image: Fig.3]). Interestingly, when I delete these Chinese characters ("`你好`" in this example, meaning "`Hello`"), I need to use the "`Backspace`" for two times (Fig.3b~d). For example, when tapping the `Backspace` for the first time, "`好`" became "`?`"; when tapping the Backspace for the second time, "`?`" then disappeared.

I tried Locale Simulator in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8), and change the software's locale to English through [Locale Simulator](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator/releases). However, an error occurred when WinBUGS opened ([image: Fig.4]). I cannot open it until I uninstall the Locale Simulator.

Comment: It is caused by character code 0xA0 in the file, the code for a non-breaking space.  Hard to guess what kind of multi-byte encoding it is using to read the file, not one of the JIS encodings.  Most important info you need to provide when troubleshooting Mojibake is your location.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Could you tell me what does the "your location" mean? Besides, I add some new information in my question (Further information Section). I was wondering if this can provide some clue.

Comment: Your "Language for non-Unicode applications" is set to a language that uses [code page 936](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT). In code page 936, the character 燚 (U+71DA) is represented by the two bytes A0 44, which when reinterpreted in code page 1252 (the code page that WinBUGS was designed for, apparently) represent "non-breaking space, capital D". This explains why you see 燚 instead of "space, capital D".

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks Chen. I know from your commment that it's because "Language for non-Unicode" problem. I tried to use Locale Simulator, but failed (see edited question). And I do not know which locale should be chosen. Could you explain a bit more?